# Creating a web page with bootstrap with content centred

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

All my pages use the entire width.

I would like the pages to conform to a page with the content having large margins automatically and I cant seem to do it.

I am using react and bootstrap.

I have tried using the following but it still uses 100% of the width...

```
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <h1>Scheduler goes here!</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I also tried adding this wrapper div

```
  <div class="col-sm-12">
```

**EDIT**:
This is not working for me at the moment. I tried to add the container as per the answer below however my navbar is appearing correctly but the page is sitting right on the left margin of the screen.

I am using react-bootstrap.

my menu, which is displaying correctly is as follows

```
  <Navbar>
            <Navbar.Header>
                <Navbar.Brand>
                    <a href="#">Jobs Ledger</a>
                </Navbar.Brand>
            </Navbar.Header>
            <Nav pullLeft>
                <LinkContainer to="/">
                    <NavItem eventKey={1}>Schedule</NavItem>
                </LinkContainer>
                <NavDropdown eventKey={2} title="Clients" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
                    <LinkContainer to="/fetchdata">
                        <MenuItem eventKey={2.1}>Fetch Data</MenuItem>
                    </LinkContainer>
                </NavDropdown>
                <NavDropdown eventKey={6} title="Original" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
                    <LinkContainer to="/counter">
                        <MenuItem eventKey={6.1}>Counter</MenuItem>
                    </LinkContainer>
                    <LinkContainer to="/fetchdata">
                        <MenuItem eventKey={6.2}>Fetch Data</MenuItem>
                    </LinkContainer>
                </NavDropdown>
            </Nav>
            <Nav pullRight>
                <LinkContainer to="/">
                    <NavItem eventKey={1}>Home</NavItem>
                </LinkContainer>
                <LinkContainer to="/counter">
                    <NavItem eventKey={2}>Counter</NavItem>
                </LinkContainer>
                <NavDropdown eventKey={3} title="Dropdown" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
                    <LinkContainer to="/fetchdata">
                        <MenuItem eventKey={3.1}>Fetch Data</MenuItem>
                    </LinkContainer>
                </NavDropdown>
            </Nav>
        </Navbar>
```

my layout page is as follows:

```
        <div class='container'>
            <div>
                <NavMenu />
            </div>
            <div>
                {this.props.body}
            </div>
        </div>
```

and my page-body (which is up hard against the left side of the screen) is

```
        return (
        <div class="container">
                <h1>Scheduler goes here!</h1>
        </div>
```

the body should be in line with the navbar...

Answer (score 0):

Set the container to a certain width, for example 50%. Then you can offset this through CSS and the rest of the child elements in the container will have 100% of the 50%.

Answer (score 0):

set the container a fixed width and put a margin in container

```
.container{
   width: 500px;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```